# Google Sheets dealership inventory that updates with new Google Forms entry

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to make an inventory list using Google Sheets and Forms that updates with new Forms responses. My work, a dealership, has two locations, and units get moved between the two so we need an easy to use up-to-date list of where the units are.

My Form has two (2) sections ADD UNIT and UPDATE UNIT. ADD UNIT fills columns A through I and UPDATE UNIT fills columns J and K.

I then have ADD UNIT and UPDATE UNIT sheets that pull their respective columns ***ADD UNIT pulls columns C through I***, then, I have an INVENTORY LIST sheet that I'm trying to combine the data and have update based on when someone submits the UPDATE UNIT form section.

Here's a link to the Google Sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOzQj9YT_xTSPT0CeE31OluW3PQyBG32ey8TQ8zUnY4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: how do you keep track of sold units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an arrayformula() vlookup() combination should work.  The internal QUERY() does the job of stacking the ADDs on top of the UPDATEs, then sorting them all by the Timestamp with the newest at the top.  This way, the stock number that the vlookup first encounters is the more recent location.

This is the formula I used, which you'll find hidden in cell G1 of the new tab called MK.Idea.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"LOCATION";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({'Form Responses 2'!C2:C,'Form Responses 2'!I2:I,'Form Responses 2'!A2:A;'Form Responses 2'!J2:K,'Form Responses 2'!A2:A},"where Col2<>'' order by Col3 desc"),2,0),COUNTA(A2:A),1)})
```

It is an arrayformula() so it is doing all the vlookups at once, without having to drag down the formula.

I also added a UNIQUE() to the formula in cell A2, that is pulling the stock numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been stuck on this for a couple weeks. And as of right now, I'm not sure what the plan for sold units is. How would I organize the sheet ascending by stock number?

Comment: If you want to solve another doubt it would be nice to open a new question, but anyways don't forget to upvote the answer that has helped you

Comment: @carter92j I added a SORT() around the UNIQUE() for the stock numbers.